# Angular 6 Input Tag: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'. ngx-tags-input

Tags: angular, tags, angular6

In my application I user Angular 6.

I try to add the `ngx-tags-input`, But when I add to module file `(TagsInputModule)` I got this error:

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
node_modules/ngx-tags-input.....
```

I try to find some solutions, but nothing work for me

1. Can I resolve this bug?
2. Another input tag that work with angular 6 and bootstarp support.

[image]

Comment: This package is deprecated check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tag-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package is deprecated and renamed to ngx-chips

Uninstall ng-tags and install

```
npm i ngx-chips
```

Ensure you import TagInputModule from ngx-chips

```
import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'; // this is needed!
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
       TagInputModule, 
       BrowserAnimationsModule,
       FormsModule,
       ReactiveFormsModule
       ...OtherModules 

})
```

Documentation:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips